# Finding a minimal integer that satisfies some conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $b,d,m$ be positive integers such that $d|m$ and $0\leq b<d$.

I want to find a minimal integer $h\in\frac{m}{bd}\mathbb{Z}\cap\frac{m}{b^2}\mathbb{Z}\cap\frac{m}{d^2}\mathbb{Z}$.

First, I found minimal integers for each set. They are $\frac{m/d}{(m/d,b)},\frac{m}{(m,b^2)}$, and $\frac{m/d}{(m/d,d)}$, where ( , ) means gcd.

So $h$ is just a least common multiple of them. We may use the rule lcm$(A,B,C)=ABC/(A,B,C)$.

I'd like to clean things up a bit more than just leaving them as they are.

However, I did not find a nice formula.

Is there some nice way to represent the number $h$?

For example, we may check that $h=m$ if $(b,d)=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac m{bd}\mathbb Z$, $\frac m{b^2}\mathbb Z$ and $\frac m{d^2}\mathbb Z$ if you’re not assuming that the denominators divide $m$?

Comment: @joriki From OP's work on finding the minimal $h$ for each of those individual cases, it seems to be the case that they are simply referring to integer multiples of those rational numbers.

Comment: @joriki It is exactly what Haran said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $h$ is an integer multiple of $\frac{m}{b^2}$ and $\frac{m}{d^2}$, then it is automatically an integer multiple of $\frac{m}{bd}$. Indeed, we have integers $x$ and $y$ such that $h = \frac{m}{b^2}x$ and $h = \frac{m}{d^2}y$, and multiplying both equations and taking square roots shows that $h = \frac{m}{bd} \sqrt{xy}$. Here, $z = \sqrt{xy}$ is rational and its square is an integer, so it must also be an integer.

Now, you only need to find the LCM of $\frac{m}{(m, b^2)}$ and $\frac{m}{(m, d^2)}$. Since the GCD of the denominators is... (can you proceed from here?)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! By letting $B=(m,b^2)$ and $D=(m,d^2)$, I found that LCM of $\frac{m}{B}$ and $\frac{m}{D}$ is $\frac{m}{(B,D)}$.